# How to find and edit the setting of vim in windows

Tags: gvim

I have installed vim in windows. I am struggling hard to find the setting of vim where I can do the changes and importing packages in vim. Any help would be really appreciated.

Regards,
Pankaj

Comment: From within vim, you can open $MYVIMRC by saying `:edit $MYVIMRC`.  This will work on any system.  You can see the path of the opened file once you do.  On Windows your vimrc file lives in your home directory as either `.vimrc` or `_vimrc`.  Learn more in vim by typing `:help vimrc`.

Comment: By the way, gVim also has a file for setup specific to the GUI version.  It's `.gvimrc` and you can get to it with `:edit $MYGVIMRC`

Comment: Sorry, “do the changes and importing packages”—can you clarify a bit? It’s not clear to me what you’re after, and that makes answering difficult